# C++ Collection Objects & iStream File Input

Tags: c++, collections

I've been stumped on my code all day today. I have a number of classes to deal with a collection of tracks and albums.
My code compiles and it reads in the file successfully, but as soon as i try to use the istream& operator in my Album Collection class it errors at run time.

This is the error:

```
   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_istream<char,struct    std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator>>(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class AlbumCollection &)" (??5@YAAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@AAVAlbumCollection@@@Z)1>C:\Users\Shardy\Desktop\AlbumDatabase\Debug\AlbumDatabase.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I would really appreciate some help. Its become frustrating. None of my books nor google is shedding any light. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The way to not leave anything out is to cut things that you think aren't relevant and then compile and run again. If the problem is still there, repeat. Then back up one step. Often the result of doing that is that you'll spot the error yourself.

Comment: Please post the *exact* run-time error.  This will help people determine where the issue is.  Also, have you tried use this newfangled device called a **debugger**.  It's very, very, helpful.

Comment: You don't state *what* the problem nor did you attempt reduce the code to only show the problem. Both are relevant steps to get sensible help. The things I spotted without knowing what the problem is are: 1. use of `std::stringstream` when `std::istringstream` (note the extra `i` is right class to use), 2. use of `std::endl` where no flush is intended or required, 3. use of a `using` directive, 4. something which looks awkward and seems to try to be `main()`.

Comment: This is the error:  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator>>(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class AlbumCollection &)" (??5@YAAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@AAVAlbumCollection@@@Z)
1>C:\Users\Shardy\Desktop\AlbumDatabase\Debug\AlbumDatabase.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
Which is why I believe its the AlbumCollection Class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

1. main.c:  If the file is successfully opened, you state that the file
   was loaded successfully.  Why bother opening the file in the first
   place if it is already loaded?  Hmm, how can that be?
2. main.c:  You never call any method that reads from the file.
3. main.c: You can use `if (file)` instead of `if (file.is_open())`
4. main.c: You're missing a closing `}` in the `if` statement.
5. main.c: You're not using `argc` or `argv` so you can declare `main`
   as `main(void)`.
6. You need to post the class declaration (header file) as well as the
   method definitions.
7. duration.cpp:  Your input method will gag when it encounters
   something not numeric or whitespace, such as ":".
8. duration.cpp: Your addition operator doesn't perform time arithmetic
   correctly, especially overflows.  Try adding "00:59:35" with
   "00:02:30".
9. duration.cpp:  Your `operator==` will return the result of the last
   expression, because you are using the comma, ',' operator.  You
   probably want to use the `&&` or logical AND operator.
10. duration.cpp: Rule of 3:  If you define a constructor, copy
     constructor or destruction you should declare all 3 and an
     assignment operator.
11. duration.cpp: Rule of Math:  If you define `operator+` or
     `operator-` you should also implement operators `+=` and `-=` as
     well.  See Boost math library.
12. duration.cpp: Rule of ordering:  If you plan to order or compare,
     you should implement operators `<, <=, ==, !=, >,` and `>=`.  Hint:
     convert the time into seconds, which should make your life easier
     when comparing.  See boost::less_than_comparable.
13. track.cpp:  You're input method reads the track name first, then
     the duration.  The data file shows duration first then track name. 
     You also have no code to deal with the field separator between
     duration and column.

    `Yep, a debugger would be helpful as well as pencil and paper to go through this code.`

Answer (score 0):

Trivially, in your main you have unmatched braces it appears. Your else statement should have a closing brace before (i.e. `} else {...}`)

More importantly, I will try to address the particular problem listed in your main (in regards to compilation). First, I list my assumptions. As it seems, your implementation and interface are appropriately separated (i.e. your class is declared in a header file and your implementation is in a source file) due to the use of your scoping (`::`) for function implementation.

Furthermore, I assume your implementation of your `operator<<` is in the same file as your AlbumCollections implementation. This is fine, however, your main file does not know this. It is currently only being compiled for the source file. Without more information, I assume this is key to your problems. You will need to forward declare this operator so it works in other files.

In your header file for album collections, include the forward declaration after your `AlbumCollection` declaration as follows (I assume you are not using the `using` directive in your header. If you are, you probably shouldn't be):

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, AlbumCollection& albums);
```

You may need to in your header `#include <iostream>` for this to properly compile. However, anywhere you include `AlbumCollection.h` (or whatever its corresponding header is called), this overload will be usable. When you link your program together, the definition you defined earlier will be used. Additionally, for this to work, it is likely that you will have to remove the `inline` qualifier from your definition.

Note that if this was the issue, the error output was probably horrendous looking. If you had this problem, a lot of the compiler error output will go away and it will be much simpler to debug any existing code compilation problems you may have.